# Is a "waiver to legal advice" valid?

Tags: contract-law

As mentioned in my other question, a client has photoshoped my contract with him. One of the terms he added was

> Legal waiver: each person signing this contract hereby waives all
>   rights to legal advice.

Is this a real thing or just nonsense?

Comment: If you have the original, have your lawyer send a letter that it was altered improperly.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are misunderstanding what this means, although without a bit more context it is hard to be 100% sure.

Usually a clause like that means that you agree that you had an opportunity to confer with a lawyer before signing the contract and despite having that opportunity decided to go ahead and sign it without receiving legal advice. This is stated because, therefore, you should be treated the same as if you conferred with a lawyer before signing the contract even though you didn't. Otherwise, if one side had a contract drafted by a lawyer and the other side didn't, the contract would be construed in favor of the unrepresented party in cases of ambiguity.

Contract terms like that are usually placed in pre-nuptial agreements and agreements between lawyers and their clients, where there is a right to afford the other party an opportunity to seek independent legal counsel before signing the contract. It would be unusual to include such a term in a vendor-purchaser of services contract.

I do not think that it is fair reading of that term that you would be prevented from seeking legal counsel in the future regarding the contract.

Comment: The OP said that it was photoshopped. This seems to mean that it was altered improperly and would just be as bad as changing any other term such as price after it was signed.

Comment: @sabbahillel It is absolutely the case that photoshopping a fake contract is bad. But, I understand this question to be asking about these kinds of terms in general and not necessarily in the context of that particular incident.